# Screen Artifacts at Shut Down when using scaled display on 15" rMBP mid 2015 running Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, screen, shutdown

I am having an issue on a week old rMBP 15" mid-2015 running Sierra 10.12.5. I use the scaled display option and have noticed that there is a concerning screen artifact that occurs when I shut down the system. Other than that, it works perfectly. Does anyone have any idea how I should approach this? I have not reinstalled the macOS, but is that the only viable solution?

[What shutdown looks like with normal scaling](https://youtu.be/uELTDS26bAI)

[What happens when I shut down with screen scaling](https://youtu.be/uEzKZ5rbI90)

Comment: I've noticed the same thing last night on my 13" early 2015 rMBP and I was worried the graphics were dying. I bought the computer in March. I did a quick test this morning to see if the problem persisted and the first shutdown went smooth, however on the second one the artifacts came back. I'll have to test again and see if the artifacts go away for good when not using the scaled display option. I hope it's not hardware related and that it can be fixed through a macOS update.

Comment: @ZanderPixels Let me know if you feel that should be a comment to the answer by William - be sure to make an answer be more about what you feel is causing this and less about "me too"

Comment: Using 10.12.6 and I get frequent artifacts on my desktop using scaled display. Apple menu bar menu's often appear half-blacked out, and sometimes the title bar in Chrome doesn't extend the full width of the window (instead being transparent for the last 30%). As soon as I disable scaled display, its all back to normal. The odd thing is scaled display is just using 'default Text Size' so its not like Im even scaling anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

macOS has gotten a lot more quirky over the past few years. I've noticed many graphical glitches, myself. This is especially visible before the OS is fully loaded and also when it shuts down or sleep/wake events are in transition.

I wouldn't worry about it, personally.

Comment: This is even more true on some Hackintosh setups